# Decomposition of ball in Banach Tarski paradox and covering a soccer ball

Tags: geometric-topology, polygons

1. Banach Tarski paradox says that it's possible to decompose a ball in $R^3$ into a finite number of disjoint subsets, which can be then reassembled into 2 identical copies of the original ball. Furthermore, 5 subsets is enough. My questions are:

   - How to do this with 5 subsets?
   - Is 5 the smallest number?
2. As I observe, a soccer ball is covered by regular pentagons and regular hexagons (but they are not flat). My questions are:

   - How to calculate the number of each type?
   - Do these pentagons have the same side? If yes, how long is it? Same questions for hexagons.
   - Why are regular pentagon and hexagon but not other regular polygons?, not other combinations?, not other types of polygons?

In both parts, let's use the unit ball (radius = 1) for simplification.

Comment: Does the soccer ball have anything to do with Banach-Tarski type decompositions? If not, you're just curious about the (possibly spherical) [truncated icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron). No algebraic topology necessary.

Comment: Yes, I'm just curious about soccer balls. Actually they are 2 seperate parts and do not relate to each other.

Comment: I think the two parts are related: with just one soccer ball and Banach-Tarski Theorem one can start soccer ball company.